# Problema con librería GD de php

Tags: php, imagen, gd

Tenemos que subir una imagen al servidor. Si la imagen no es transparente funciona todo perfectamente. El problema viene cuando la imagen, o bien sea `jpg` o sea `png`, tiene una parte transparente.

Si es transparente, se sube la foto recortada bien pero totalmente en negro. No se ve nada.

¿Cómo se puede hacer para subir una imagen que tenga o sea transparente?

Mi código para cortar la imagen:

```
// Ruta de la imagen original
$rutaImagenOriginal = $rutaCompleta;
$img_original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rutaImagenOriginal);
$max_ancho = 100;
$max_alto = 100;
list($ancho,$alto) = getimagesize($rutaImagenOriginal);
$x_ratio = $max_ancho / $ancho;
$y_ratio = $max_alto / $alto;
$ancho_final = $max_ancho;
$alto_final = $max_alto;

$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final,$alto_final);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$img_original,0,0,0,0,$ancho_final, $alto_final,$ancho,$alto);
$calidad = 100;

imagejpeg($tmp,$rutaCompleta,$calidad);
imagedestroy($img_original);
```

He probado con las funciones [`imagecolorallocated()`](http://php.net/imagecolorallocated) pero no quita la transparencia. También he probado con [`imagesavealpha()`](http://php.net/imagesavealpha) y tampoco quita la transparencia.

Comment: Una imagen JPEG no puede tener transparencia. ¿Quieres generar un PNG que mantenga la transparencia o un JPEG (como está en tu código) y reemplazar la transparencia por un color fijo? Si usas [`imagealphablending()`](http://php.net/imagealphablending) y lo desactivas los pixeles resultado de hacer operaciones en imágenes mantendrán transparencia, en caso contrario los resultados son siempre pixeles opacos.

Comment: Si una imagen png, desde windows se cambia la extension manualmente y se pone jpg en vez de png, la imagen será jpg pero sigue siendo fondo transparente. Lo que quiero es lo segundo, reemplazar la transparencia por un color fijo, ya que si la subo sin hacer esto la imagen se ve totalmente en negro.

Comment: Error, la imagen no será JPEG, seguirá siendo una imagen PNG con una extensión `.jpg`. Eso no lo convierte en un JPEG con transparencia. Prueba lo que te he dicho y ponle el color de fondo que quieras antes de hacer la copia.

Comment: Efectivamente, es lo que quiero hacer, pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es, como te dije en los comentarios, que una imagen sigue siendo de formato PNG aunque le cambies la extensión a `.jpg`, por lo que debes detectar el formato real de la imagen para poder abrirlo de manera correcta.

## Usando `imagecreatefromstring`

Te recomiendo usar [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring) para forzar la detección automática del formato de imagen si no quieres complicar tu código.

```
<?php
// Ruta de la imagen original
$rutaImagenOriginal = $rutaCompleta;
/* Forzamos la autodetección a partir de los datos del archivo */
$img_original = imagecreatefromstring(
  file_get_contents($rutaImagenOriginal)
);
if ($img_original === false) {
    die('Formato de imagen no soportado');
}
$max_ancho = 100;
$max_alto = 100;
list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($rutaImagenOriginal);
$x_ratio = $max_ancho / $ancho;
$y_ratio = $max_alto / $alto;
$ancho_final = $max_ancho;
$alto_final = $max_alto;

/* Creamos la imagen de destino */
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final, $alto_final);
/* Alojamos el color de fondo y rellenamos con él la imagen */
$fondo = imagecolorallocate($tmp, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($tmp, 0, 0, $fondo);
/* Con "true" forzamos la mezcla de la imagen usando la transparencia */
imagealphablending($tmp, true);
/* Copiamos la imagen con mezcla de transparencia */
imagecopyresampled(
  $tmp, $img_original,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  $ancho_final,
  $alto_final,
  $ancho,
  $alto
);

/* Damos salida a la imagen en formato JPEG (100% implica pérdida de calidad)
 Cuidado con $rutaCompleta que podría contener una extensión errónea */
$calidad = 100;
imagejpeg($tmp, $rutaCompleta, $calidad);
/* O podemos dar salida a la imagen en formato PNG (sin pérdida de calidad) */
/*imagepng($tmp, $rutaCompleta);*/
?>
```

## Usando `finfo_file`

Otra alternativa sería hacer uso de [`finfo_file`](http://php.net/finfo-file):

```
<?php
// Ruta de la imagen original
$rutaImagenOriginal = $rutaCompleta;
/* Abrimos el archivo según su contenido */
switch(finfo_file($rutaImagenOriginal)) {
  case 'image/jpeg':
    $img_original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rutaImagenOriginal);
    break;
  case 'image/png':
    $img_original = imagecreatefrompng($rutaImagenOriginal);
    break;
  default:
    die('Formato de imagen no soportado');
}
if ($img_original === false) {
    die('Error abriendo imagen');
}
$max_ancho = 100;
$max_alto = 100;
list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($rutaImagenOriginal);
$x_ratio = $max_ancho / $ancho;
$y_ratio = $max_alto / $alto;
$ancho_final = $max_ancho;
$alto_final = $max_alto;

/* Creamos la imagen de destino */
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final, $alto_final);
/* Alojamos el color de fondo y rellenamos con él la imagen */
$fondo = imagecolorallocate($tmp, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($tmp, 0, 0, $fondo);
/* Con "true" forzamos la mezcla de la imagen usando la transparencia */
imagealphablending($tmp, true);
/* Copiamos la imagen con mezcla de transparencia */
imagecopyresampled(
  $tmp, $img_original,
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  $ancho_final,
  $alto_final,
  $ancho,
  $alto
);

/* Damos salida a la imagen en formato JPEG (100% implica pérdida de calidad)
 Cuidado con $rutaCompleta que podría contener una extensión errónea */
$calidad = 100;
imagejpeg($tmp, $rutaCompleta, $calidad);
/* O podemos dar salida a la imagen en formato PNG (sin pérdida de calidad) */
/*imagepng($tmp, $rutaCompleta);*/
?>
```

## Otras

- [`exif_imagetype`](http://php.net/exif-imagetype)
- [`getimagesize`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize)

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia . No se como agradecerte tu aportación ya que me está funcionando a la perfección y llevaba bastantes días con esto. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: El agradecimiento es suficiente :) fue un placer.

Answer (score 0):

Si subes un PNG no te sirve `imagecreatefromjpeg`. Tienes que determinar el tipo de imagen primero y si es PNG, usar `imagecreatefrompng`.

Hay dos maneras de hacer esto. La manera sencilla: usas la extensión:

```
$rutaImagenOriginal = $rutaCompleta;
$filename_parts= explode('.',$rutaImagenOriginal);
$extension = array_pop( $filename_parts );

if($extension === 'jpg') {
    $img_original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rutaImagenOriginal);
} else {
    $img_original = imagecreatefrompng($rutaImagenOriginal);
}
```

(esto se puede mejorar usando un `switch` para que acepte tanto `jpg` como `jpeg`, y para aceptar también imágenes `gif`).

La otra manera, usar `GD` (que ya tienes instalada) para detectar el tipo de imagen usando [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). La salida de esa función es un array que incluye el mimetype.

```
$image_info = getimagesize($rutaImagenOriginal);

if($image_info['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {
    $img_original = imagecreatefromjpeg($rutaImagenOriginal);
} else {
    $img_original = imagecreatefrompng($rutaImagenOriginal);
}
```

Comment: Esto de hacer "imagecratefrompng" también lo probé a hacer pero si lo hago y subo una imagen .png no me funciona. Se ve el símbolo de una imagen de windows pero intento abrirla y me pone que el archivo es erróneo o está dañado.